# About the pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following programm,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int marks[]={20,65,45,68,89};
    int *x,*y;
    x=&marks[2];
    y=&marks[4];
    printf("%p\n%p\n"x,y);
    printf("%p\n%p\n",y-x,*y-*x);
    return 0;
}
```

When I want to print out the value of `y-x`, the console should give me a output equal to the difference between the addresses of the corresponding pointers. After all, we know that `x` and `y` are having addresses ('some integer value'). However it is not so. Why?

Comment: can you rephrase and remove the blockquote? and why are you calling stackoverflow sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the console must give me a output equal to the difference between the addresses of the corresponding pointers

... and it does. For me, it outputs `2`. If you compare the addresses, you see that they are separated by 8 bytes, which is 2 `int`s, which is the answer you sought.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer subtraction does not simply subtract the addresses but rather return the distance between two array elements (in terms of arary elements).

So `y - x` is not a pointer but an integer of the value `2` - and to printf it, you shold use `%d` formatting, now `%p`.

Comment: Technically we don't know if the format is %d either, that depends on how big ptrdiff_t is.

Answer (score 2):

If you print the differences using %p, you will probably get something that's a bit hard to read.

The proper way is probably to use %lu, and cast:

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) (y - x));
```

Printing the integer quantity `*y - *x` as %p seems totally confused.

Comment: Just for clarification (to the OP): Subtracting two pointers to the same object by definition will yield a intptr_t type R value. So this typecast is not neccesary to convert a pointer to an integer type, but to make sure, that the integer yielding from the pointer arithmetic is properly passed to any interpreted by printf.

Answer (score 1):

The result of subtraction of 2 pointers in the same array is the distance between those pointers in array, so `y-x` should equal 2 in your example.

To get difference between addresses cast them to some integer before substracting:

```
printf("%d",(size_t)y-(size_t)x);
```

Answer (score 1):

`y-x` will evaluate to 2 - since the distance in between them is 2 ints.

If you print e.g.  `(char *) y - (char *) x` you will get the distance in characters